# Retrieve value from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on `SQL` in which i need to trigger a values in following situation

My Question is :

I need a query  which should  retrieve the values from single SQL table, and the Query result will be in more than one rows, Till now not any problem i am facing. now i need to print the results in single row

**My Example**

I have 4 columns in my table namely **AutoArtId**, **empArtStage**, **ArtStageCurrStat**, **PgsCompleted**

when i invoke `select * from my table where ArtStageCurrStat=S1010` .The result will be in single row, that's fine.

But when i invoke the query like `select * from table`, it displaying two rows with all record because my table has originally two rows.

Now my question is shall i have a query which should merge **the two rows values into single row** while retrieving the record from table

*Refer my image below*

[image]

In Above image is the result i got, So ..

**Is  there any possibility to give a output from**

[image]

To

[image]

(This picture i have designed, i expect this result)

Any Suggestion for this....

Comment: Can there be more than two rows?

Comment: @Joni..No, retrieved record has only two rows . but when i print the values in front-end it should retrieve as one row , as i mentioned in last image..

Comment: Could you specify what dbms and version you are using please? possible alternative approaches differ according to vendor and version

Comment: @user..No, it is not version oriented..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis of what is seen, a generic SQL query like this would "flatten" those rows into a single row (but the 2 PgsCompleted values need different column names).

```
    select
        AutoArtId
      , empArtStage
      , MIN(ArtStageCurrStat) as ArtStageCurrStat 
      , MIN(PgsCompleted) as PgsCompleted1
      , MAX(PgsCompleted) as PgsCompleted2
    from YourTable
    group by AutoArtId, empArtStage
```

Some questions emerge aboout more or less than 2 rows, this may help:

```
    select
        AutoArtId
      , empArtStage
      , MIN(ArtStageCurrStat) as ArtStageCurrStat 
      , MIN(PgsCompleted) as PgsCompleted1
      , MAX(PgsCompleted) as PgsCompleted2
      , count(*) as num_of
    from YourTable
    group by AutoArtId, empArtStage
    having count(*) <> 2
```

Here is an approach that uses row_number() which is available in SQL 2008. It assumes you have some field(s) in the table that will allow distinction of oldest and newest (here I have used an autonumbered ID) - AND the assumption that it is the oldest and newest that are the relevant record pairs. In **[this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a1ef/1)** I dummied up some sample data representing one group of 3 records and another of a single record.

```
SELECT
        AutoArtId
      , empArtStage
      , MIN(ArtStageCurrStat) AS ArtStageCurrStat
      , MIN(PgsCompleted) AS PgsCompleted1
      , MAX(PgsCompleted) AS PgsCompleted2
FROM (
      SELECT
              AutoArtId
            , empArtStage
            , ArtStageCurrStat
            , PgsCompleted
            , row_number() over (partition BY AutoArtId, empArtStage
                                  ORDER BY ID ASC) AS oldest
            , row_number() over (partition BY AutoArtId, empArtStage
                                  ORDER BY ID DESC) AS newest
      FROM YourTable
      ) AS derived
WHERE oldest = 1 OR newest = 1
GROUP BY
        AutoArtId
      , empArtStage
```

Comment: Thank u , but we cannot predict the min and max values

Comment: @kark, it would be very helpful if you specified the dbms type and version - for example lead/lag may be useful or row_number() but without knowing what your dbms supports we are rather limited in possibilites

Comment: thanks (no lead/lag is available in 2008) but you do have row_number() - are there any other fields in the table such as a date created? or an autonumbered identity? (typically ID)

Comment: You were fantastic, Was blinded by your answer, Really great answer with clear explanation..

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by and get the two values with MAX and MIN:

```
SELECT AutoArtId, empArtStage, min(PgsCompleted), max(PgsCompleted) 
FROM table GROUP BY AutoArtId, empArtStage;
```

Comment: Good one, that's fine for this table, but in case the  `PgsCompleted`differed , we cannot predict the third ans fourth position right. i mentioned that my result will be two rows..

Comment: @kark, the order of the rows in the table is not guaranteed to be fixed so even if today you get 111 first and 33 second tomorrow you may get different results. To get the rows in a particular order you can use ORDER BY.

Comment: @Joni i just got the answer which is working now,,Refer the accepted answer, Thanks for your time